# can we convert a normal results.log file to xunit or allure xml format?

Tags: jenkins, xml-parsing, python-3.5, xunit, allure

My python framework generates results in a txt file like below:

```
$ python3.5 Regression.py ALL  

TCID 1 : TEST CASE 1 : PASS  
TCID 2 : TEST CASE 2 : PASS  
TCID 3 : TEST CASE 3 : FAIL  
TCID 4 : TEST CASE 4 : ERROR  

**================= TEST SUMMARY ====================**  
Total Passed Tests : 2  
Total Failed Tests : 1  
Total Skipped Tests : 1  
Total Time         : 0:04:03.64  
Average per test   : 0:00:11.602254  
Total  Tests       : 4  
**================= END TEST SUITE ==================**
```

As this is an independent test framework which is neither pytest not nosetests, is there any way i can convert this txt to xml(xunit or allure type) and see results in allure report or any other type of report in Jenkins ?

Comment: You'd better use Allure in your tests so it will generate all needed files and no conversion will be needed.

Comment: @DenisKoreyba : any guidance how can i use allure in my framework ? right now all I am doing is saving console logs to a file. A sample shall be highly appreciated ...

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry you told you use a specific test framework. So seems to me that if there is no adapter for it you are not able to use Allure with it. Only to create an adapter...

Comment: @DenisKoreyba  Ohh !!! So now way I can convert the format to allure or xunit ?

Comment: You need to have a parser that will convert it. If there is one for you framework that you are the lucky one. I bet you'd need to do it by yourself :). Yet I don't think it's too hard to implement. BUT maybe it's easier to change your test framework :)

Comment: This is simple python framework and i have not used any default framework like nose or pytest. Also it has more than 1000 tests so impossible to migrate them all to new framework.